# Select with diff unique fields

Tags: mysql, search, distinct

i have a little problem with a sql statement.
my database looks like:

```
ArticleNo | ArticleName | EAN          | PZN | ISBN | ManuArtNo
----------------------------------------------------------------
13892     | Test        | 823912839182 |     |      | Test
38741     | Test        |              |     |      |
89389     | Paper       |              |     |      | PaperComp
```

For the Product Search i need a select which give me the following output:

```
ArticleNo | ArticleName | EAN          | PZN | ISBN | ManuArtNo
---------------------------------------------------------------
13892     | Test        | 823912839182 |     |      | Test
89389     | Paper       |              |     |      | PaperComp
```

so i would like to group by some fields.

so i could do a search on ArticleName without having duplicates...

anyone could give me a hint, how i could do this?

thanks advance

Comment: How do you select ArticleNo 13892 over 38741?

Comment: "anyone could give me a hint, how i could do this?" You could start by actually defining what you want to do. Then take a crack at it and come back and ask a *specific* question instead about where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: hims067: this was only the view from select * from products; i would like to filter the products for unique ArticleName's, but it could be that the ArticleName is diffrent so i will look for the EAN/PZN/ISBN/ManuArtNo to get unique Products

Answer (score 0):

[GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) will do the trick.

See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) as well.

```
select * from Table1 group by ArticleName
order by null;
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b1d16/3/1)